# How to reference Context data within pivottable.js function

Tags: django, pivottable.js

I have a django project setup. I am working on adding a new page with a pivottable, using pivottable.js (https://github.com/nicolaskruchten/pivottable)

My issue is that I am not able to load the csv data from views.py context, {{data}}, from within the pivottable.js jQuery function.

In my views.py:

```
def sysdev_pivottable(request):
    context = {}
    csvString = ""
    with open("W:\\data.csv", 'rb') as csvfile:
        reader= csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
        for row in reader:
            csvString = csvString + ','.join(row)

    context['data'] = csvString
    template = loader.get_template('pivottable.html')
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

In pivottable.html:

...

```
<h1> Test load: {{ data }}</h1> #this displays data properly
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function()
{
    var input1 = "1,2,3,4" #test data declared within the function()
    $("#output").pivotUI(input1, {}); #this loads properly
    var input2 = {{data}} ##this doesn't work, would break the rest of the <script>
});
    </script>
        <div id="output" style="margin: 10px;">
        </div>
```

I don't know how to load `{{data}}` properly from within the `$(function(){})`. From outside of the `$(function(){})` I can load `{{data}}` properly. Thanks for the help

Comment: Try to change `var input2 = {{data}}` to `var input2 = "{{data}}"` and check if an error appears

Comment: @AnnaVracheva I tried that too, it results in the webpage not loading anything as it throws an error i can't see. The problem is that any reference to the context data (any {{key}}) from within the $(function()) block seems to cause the whole <script> block to fail out.

Comment: Have you added `jquery.js` script and `pivottable.js` before your script? I checked your code and it's work if `data` wraped in quotes. What is error in console?

Comment: @AnnaVracheva Thanks for confirming for me, you really helped point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

As @AnnaVracheva mentioned, my main issue was forgetting the quotation around my {{data}}. In addition I used jquery.csv (https://github.com/evanplaice/jquery-csv) to format my input data, and everything worked.

```js
$(function() { var input = $.csv.toArrays("{{data}}") $("#output").pivotUI(input, { rows: ["RowValue"], cols: ["ColValue"] }); });
</script>
<div id="output" style="margin: 10px;">
</div>
```